# Most efficient way to Sort a large list of Objects

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following simple class,  containing a String and an Int.

```
private static class SuggestionAndScore
{
    private String suggestion; 
    private int score;  
}
```

I will have a List of these objects which may contain up on **500,000** items.
What is the best way to sort this based on the value of score?  Should I have the class implement Comparator and use Collections.sort on it or it there a better way?
Performance is critical so hence my question as I want to make sure I get the best solution.

Comment: 1. Make it work (with your suggestion to use a Comparator with Collections.sort) 2. Profile 3. If performance is not good enough, optimise.

Comment: How do you know performance is critical without implementing a solution first? Start with `Collections.sort()` and if it isn't good enough, then you can start think about better alternatives.

Comment: If sorting is not fast enough, wonder if you really need everything to be sorted. It is possible to get the n-th highest scores without sorting everything.

Comment: The list will be immutable once it is created.  Thing is most of the time it will have < 1000 items but it MAY have up to 500,000. As I don't want any memory issues or unacceptable performance issues with large numbers I guess it's a compromise I need. Comparator works fine with 500,000.  Would using a Tree Set be easier on memory resources?

Comment: You might be surprised about how fast an in memory sort of 500,000 items is, especially if the object comparison is simply on an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your objects are unique then use `TreeSet`. Gives the best performance since the objects are already stored in sorted order. (You need not even call Collections.sort())

Comment: Depending on the requirements, using a `TreeSet` could easily be an overkill here.

Comment: @Jan your statement is highly debatable. Depending on the requirements, using a `TreeSet` could give great performance.

Comment: @PC It isn't debatable at all. It all depends on how many times you're going to modify the list. If the answer is never, `TreeSet` is an overkill. If you build the list dynamically, `TreeSet` is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to understand that the sorting methods loads the entire collection into memory, so in case your SuggestionAndScore object is big (probably because of the big suggestion string), you will consume huge amount of memory and could potentially even crash the system. If you believe memory could be a concern then use in-place sorting. If memory isnt a problem then use TreeSet.